# Stop condition for nls.lm

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting

please let me ask you about the control of the finishing condition for nls.lm.

Bellow you can see the log that nls.lm shows when it is trying to fit my data. Since the target value for the parameters are {0, 0.05, 0.5, 0}, does any of you know the value that I should set for ptol or ftol if I want the function stopping at iteration 29, 30 or 31?

Thank you in advance.

```
It.   23, RSS = 3.90984e-07, Par. =  0.000336657  0.0496077   0.499512   0.400874 
It.   24, RSS = 2.75825e-08, Par. =  0.000167468  0.0497082   0.500001   0.200901 
It.   25, RSS = 1.85953e-09, Par. =  8.30194e-05  0.0497505   0.500002  0.0996384 
It.   26, RSS = 1.45254e-10, Par. =  3.99165e-05  0.0497721   0.500003  0.0479206 
It.   27, RSS = 1.37006e-11, Par. =  1.68307e-05  0.0497836   0.500003  0.0202179 
It.   28, RSS = 7.29574e-13, Par. =  4.00511e-06    0.04979   0.500002  0.00481911 
It.   29, RSS = 1.54053e-15, Par. =  9.06664e-08  0.0497919        0.5  0.000110152 
It.   30, RSS = 8.29473e-18, Par. =  1.48169e-08  0.0497919        0.5  1.77622e-05 
It.   31, RSS = 6.28718e-18, Par. =  1.31978e-08  0.0497919        0.5  1.58192e-05 
It.   32, RSS = 5.19729e-18, Par. =  1.20234e-08   0.049792        0.5  1.44384e-05 
It.   33, RSS = 4.26672e-18, Par. =  1.0823e-08   0.049792        0.5  1.29703e-05
```

Comment: See `help("nls.control")`. Maybe you can do it with `maxiter`, maybe with `tol`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, Rui.  Setting maxiter seems a bad choice since initial values may not be so close to real values as in the example shown (library creators recommend the number of parameters*100).  As I can read in the libary documentation, the related parameters for nls.control are ptol, ftol and gtol. I would like to stop when RSS=1e-18 is reached.